# Provide strongly typed access to the session object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

What is the best way to provide strongly typed access to the session object?  I am planning on turning on Option Strict, which is causing the compiler to complain about my lazy programming technique of directly accessing the session object:

```
Dim blah As Integer = Session("Blah")
```

My initial thought is to create a class that wraps the session and provides strongly typed properties for the information stored in the session.  However, I cannot decide if the class should be a singleton, or instantiated on every use, or where the code should reside (i.e. within the web project or within a class library).

I'm leaning towards a singleton in my class library, but I don't know if that is the best solution, or if I am missing any other possibilities.

Proposed Solution:

```
Public Class SessionAccess
    Public Shared Property Blah(ByVal session As HttpSessionState) As Integer
        Get
            Return Convert.ToInt32(session("Blah"))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            session("Blah") = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Code Behind:

```
Dim blah As Integer = SessionAccess.Blah(session)
```

Comment: Why are you doing this?  What problem are you trying to solve? That might be of value. :-D

Comment: I'm putting on Option Strict so that developer B doesn't come along and stuff a string in "Blah", causing code that developer A writes to crash.  Putting it in a class that both developers use forces them to both treat "Blah" as an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either my proposal is the "standard" way to do it, or else no one wraps their session access, since this question hasn't received very many answers.

I did find one line in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688696/building-asp-net-application-best-practices/1688822#1688822) that mentioned creating a SessionManager:

- Wrap the ASP.NET Session with a
  SessionManager to avoid development
  mistakes in spelling, etc. when
  referencing items from Session.

I have not thought of any reason to not use a singleton class to provide typed access to the session, so that is the solution I went with in the project.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my original answer as @Jason Berkan made a very good point when he questioned my answer.  Jason, I think this idea is fine.

The only thing I would change in your code example is to check to ensure that the session variable exists.

Comment: For sure - the code in the examples is stripped down.  Once in a class, checks for null values would be added, as well as moving "Blah" into a string constant.