# What is the best tips to improve the Application Performance in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net

Can any help regarding the performance improvement in Asp.Net?The best practise tips for asp.net performance improvement?

Comment: What specific performance problems are you experiencing?

Comment: My application goes slow .I don't understand why it happening like that?

Comment: neither do we.  what part of your application goes slow?  maybe we can help if you give some specifics.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question to answer because the Performance of an ASP.Net application is not only bound to page processing or bandwidth usage but also in the code and Algorithms you have written.  If you use data source then the Performance of the Queries and ADo.Net. The Basic thing you might be asking is to improve page processing by [Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c.aspx), etc..

Have a look here for a detailed description of Best Patterns and Practice (Though its old ..published in 2004 but still helps).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647215.aspx

Or better consider this (For .Net4) . It list all performance related Documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668225.aspx

**Update**

If you are looking for specific *stuff* slowing your page load
Use firebug's Net panel and monitor which resource is taking more time. Or as suggested by another answer use Tracing to check this out.

Answer (score 1):

What is the best drug to get healthier? It all depends on what is your health problem. The same thing is with ASP.NET performance. First, find what is your bottleneck, a single most slow down factor. Then fix it, retest performance and, if more speed is necessary, go to the previous step.

How to find a bottleneck?  If you really have no clue where to start, then start from analyzing your waterfall diagram. To create one from your client, use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). To create it from different Internet geographies use [WebPagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/). The waterfall will show whether the bottleneck is on the server or network, and also whether it is caused by main ASPX page or by resources (scripts, images, CSS). If the server and network are fast enough, then check slowness in the browser using Firebug or [dynaTrace Ajax edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) that can trace DOMContentLoaded/load events in browser. If the bottleneck is on the server, find out whether it is the database or application. Use database profiler and .NET profiler, for example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308816/any-good-free-net-profiler) question.

How to fix bottlenecks?  Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647787.aspx) Microsoft resource, but there are many others for each type of bottlenecks.

If you add the “performance“ tag to your question you may get more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Set trace="true" in the page directive. Reload the page and look for any obvious delays in the page life-cycle event handlers, particularly where you are accessing a database.

Also, use the Firefox Web Developer toolbar to obtain a friendly overview of the image file sizes and other static file sizes, CSS, JS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of questions and answers on ASP.NET performance here on Stackoverflow. Here's [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148721/how-to-decrease-the-page-load-time-in-asp-net-application/3148947#3148947) and a [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net+performance) on the `ASP.NET` and `Performance` tags yields plenty of results.

What problems are you facing exactly?