# Long pause on page loads

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net app, which uses a SQL Server database on a hosted plan.

When I click a button to go to a new screen there is a long pause before the page loads.

Using Chrome, I see this:

[image]

What does 'Waiting' indicate as the issue? Is it a problem where, on the server, it's taking too long to get the data? Slow query maybe? Any way I can debug this?

The line which shows this pause is actually the page on which the 'Redirect' happens, after a postback.

Comment: What resource is that trying to get, I can't make out from the picture? looks like something.com ?

Comment: It's a page called 'landing.aspx', on a small site I am trying to make, accuproject.com

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Chrome will only tell you which resources are being loaded and time taken for each.  To debug this, you need a tool like [Antz Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), which will help you find bottlenecks in the C# code.  It will highlight which lines are taking the longest, in a hierarchical fashion, so you can drill down to the culprit.

If you find that it's a line calling your database, then you can use **Query Analyser** in **SSMS** to investigate the SQL query.  If you post the code for the `page_load()` event, I will update the answer with anything that looks obvious.

**Other things to look out for** will be the resources the page is loading, `images`, `javascript` files, `external libraries` etc.  If you have a lot of Javascript files, make sure they are the `.min` version, or if the files are custom, maybe consider adding the code in one file, and [minifying](http://jscompress.com/) the production version.  Make sure any images are small in size, as this will take up bandwidth.

take a look at [Tips for authoring fast-loading HTML pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Tips_for_authoring_fast-loading_HTML_pages) for some other examples.

You'll also find some good tips here [How to decrease the page load time in ASP.NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148721/how-to-decrease-the-page-load-time-in-asp-net-application)